# Why prohibit static allocation in c++?

Tags: c++, object, dynamic, static, creation

What is the point with making the constructor of a class private and having a getInstance method which returns a new instance? When do you want to only allow dynamic object creation and why? I have seen examples of this and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly done when class instances manage their own lifetime, e.g. they will subscribe to some event that comes asynchronously.  If the instance were destroyed before the event arrives, the event dispatcher would use a wild pointer and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: For example, a class that uses [shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) to create asynchronous completion handlers requires that class instances be created in a particular way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Exactly.  Reference counting and private constructors/destructors are often found together.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious example would be if the class manages its own lifetime. Allowing static allocation would result in a double free.

Answer (score 0):

Usually its because the programmer wants to control the objects that are alive at any time. Valid use cases are:

- the Singleton pattern
- keeping an implicit list of all objects alive to facilitate operations on all these objects
- reusing objects that are already alive

The last objective usually also calls for reference counting to be able to destroy the objects once they are not needed any more, and requires objects to be logically constant. One usage of this is interning strings for performance (it allows strings to be compared by comparing their pointers!).

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be when you want to control the specific type being created as one of several possible sub-types that the calling application does not need to be aware of.

For example you may want to obtain a `Connection` to download a resource from a `URL` and the `URL` will determine which specific type of `Connection` is returned - `HTTPConnection`, `HTTPSConnection`, `FTPConection` etc...